# Rails Active_storage ActiveStorage::IntegrityError on test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

On a rails 5.2, I save a canvas as blob and send it on azur storage via Active storage.

On my machine, with development environnement, png is created perfectly and perfectly send to the azur blob and I get it attach to the model.

But on the Test machine ( with test environnement) I get a ActiveStorage::IntegrityError when I attach the blob to the image.

the javascript that send the png

```
            var project_id = 2;
            var csrf_token  = $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content");
            var project_metadata = new FormData();
            project_metadata.append("utf8","✓");
            project_metadata.append("authenticity_token",csrf_token);
            project_metadata.append("projet_id",project_id.toString());
            project_metadata.append("commit","Create Projet");
            var file_name = "rdc.png";
            var upload_file_field = that.drawing.getElement().toBlob(function(blob) {
                var file = new File([blob], file_name, {type: "image/png", lastModified: Date.now()});
                var url = "/projects/"+project_id.toString()+"/store_plan"
                project_metadata.append("images",file,file_name);   
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: url,
                  data: project_metadata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,                   
                  success: function(){
                    console.log("images save");
                  }
                });
            })
```

The controller

```
def store_plan
  @project.images.attach(io: params["images"].to_io, filename: params["images"].original_filename)
end
```

The storage.yml

```
azure_dev:
   service: AzureStorage
   storage_account_name: "XXXXX"
   storage_access_key: "..."
   container: projectsdevelopment

test:
   service: AzureStorage
   storage_account_name: "XXXXX"
   storage_access_key: "..."
   container: projectstest
```

My dev machine is a mac book pro, my test machine is an Ubuntu.

Well don't understand why I get an ActiveStorage::IntegrityError on test and everything is ok on development?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but I had a similar problem when trying to batch upload a bunch of dummy files to records. I ended up just calling `rescue` to get out of the error. Not ideal, but all my files are successfully attached so I think maybe it's worth an issue on GH if you can send a minimal test repo.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION

I finally use `fetch` instead of `$.ajax({})` and it's work on both side.